# Gradle Android communicate with maven repository Authentication error

Tags: android, maven, gradle, maven-2

I have these in my gradle build but when I try to compile `compile'com.livegenic:livegenic-core:2.0.0'` it gives me `Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated`

Maybe I am using my gradle srcipt to authenticate wrong way?

```
repositories {
        maven {
            credentials {
                username 'admin'
                password '*********'
            }
            url 'https://cloudbuild.livegenic.com/nexus/content/repositories/test_kirill/'
        }
    }
```

EDITED: 
This is the trace of error

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://cloudbuild.livegenic.com/nexus/content/repositories/test_kirill/com/livegenic/livegenic-core/2.0.0/livegenic-core-2.
0.0.pom'.
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:83)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRawGet(HttpClientHelper.java:69)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performGet(HttpClientHelper.java:73)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.openResource(HttpResourceAccessor.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.openResource(HttpResourceAccessor.java:34)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultExternalResourceConnector.openResource(DefaultExternalResourceConnector.java:41)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.ProgressLoggingExternalResourceAccessor.openResource(ProgressLoggingExternalResourceAccessor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.DefaultExternalResourceRepository.getResource(DefaultExternalResourceRepository.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.getResource(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:75)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.downloadStaticResource(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:90)
        ... 133 more        
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:572)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:640)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DecompressingHttpClient.execute(DecompressingHttpClient.java:137)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DecompressingHttpClient.execute(DecompressingHttpClient.java:118)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHttpRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:113)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.executeGetOrHead(HttpClientHelper.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:81)
        ... 142 more
```

Comment: usually it happens if the https is not trusted

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti So I better ask the one who made the repository? Or it is my mistake because I can access it from browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `https` try using `http`

```
repositories {
    maven {
        credentials {
            username 'admin'
            password '*********'
        }
        url 'http://cloudbuild.livegenic.com/nexus/content/repositories/test_kirill/'
    }
}
```

As pointed out yes this defeats the protections of https, 100% agreed.  The only real solution is to have the server fix it's certificate.  However it maybe the case that some enterprise firewall is resigning all the traffic, yes it happens.  If you have access to that cert being used to resign everything then you could import the cert to your tool chain like this

```
$ cd $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security
$ mv cacerts cacerts.orig
$ chmod 444 cacerts.orig
$ cp cacerts.orig cacerts
$ chmod 664 cacerts
$ $JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -keystore cacerts -import -alias MyAlias -file /path/to/myCert.cer
```

Be sure you run the keytool import as a user who is able to modify the Java keystore on your system. For me on a Mac that was root.

Comment: This would definitely work, but it should be noted that this is generally a bad suggestion. While great for troubleshooting, this should not be considered a fix. This unfortunately defeats the whole point of http*s*. As a sensible software practitioner, it is a good idea to put some effort into getting https to work rather than bypassing it completely. To give a silly analogy, when faced with a problem of a key getting jammed in a lock ocassionally, this solution says: "Easy, don't lock your door, problem solved."

Comment: @RaGe Yes, I asked my teammate to change repo to http and it works but I think https is needed.
He says there is problem with trus-certificate on windows...

Comment: @Rage, agreed.
OP, if you want to use https then see my edit, but depending on your company and if they will give you the cert this solution may not work for you.